# PDF files in SharePoint Online 2016

Tags: pdf, online

By default PDF files open in Web mode or we have an option to open PDF's in Browser mode.

But my PDF files have comments which are not visible in browser or Web Mode :( Is there a way to open PDF files in SharePoint online using Adobe Reader or Acrobat?

Or do we have any other PDF tool that will integrate with SharePoint Online 2016?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add the [Adobe Document Cloud](https://documentcloud.adobe.com/o365pdf/start.html?trackingid=XB5KHQN1&mv=in-product&mv2=acrobat) addin for ODfB/SPO. This will allow you to open PDFs in Adobe's cloud. Commenting and markup are free, other features require an Adobe Doc Cloud subscription per user.

Comment: Thank You for the help